# MVC 4 SImpleMembership with LDAP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ldap, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking to try out using simpleMembership but connect it to our LDAP.  I haven't seen anything online about doing this, only with SQL.  Does anyone know if it's possible and could lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd need to create a class which inherits from ExtendedMembershipProvider and write the LDAP implementation. There's no built-in LDAP support.

See [this post for more information on how SimpleMembership works in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Was hoping they'd have something integrated since they had already added external logins such as Google, Yahoo, Facebook, etc.

Comment: What is the rational behind not implementing LDAP support? In our environment a majority of our apps run off of Active Directory for Single Sign On purposes. It was pretty disheartening to create a new MVC 4 project in VS 2012 and have been forced into a situation where we have no "easy way" to implement Active Directory Forms Auth.  We are having to tear apart the Account section to get this work.  I can't believe that we're the only shop in this situation.

Comment: @ScottLance  Trust me, you're not the only shop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider may be able to be configured to connect to a different LDAP provider. You mentioned in an earlier response that you're using Active Directory so it may even be a non-issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx